# Tensorflow.keras doesn't enable to my project

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I try to use tensorflow library and it doesn't work. I don't know what to do. BTW. Mac silicon.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/belka/PycharmProjects/golubov_laba_1/main.py", line 2, in 
from tensorflow import keras
ImportError: cannot import name 'keras' from 'tensorflow' (unknown location)

Process finished with exit code 1

I'd tried to uninstall tensor flow and used the apple require to this library

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Hey try using this command

```
%pip3 install tensorflow
```

or

```
!pip3 install tensorflow
```

Let us know if it worked

Answer (score 0):

As you are on a Mac silicon (I guess M1, but anyway), you should try to use `tensorflow_macos` instead of `tensorflow`. To install it, you can download it from GitHub:

```
bash -c "$(curl -fsS  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apple/tensorflow_macos/master/scripts/download_and_install.sh)"
```

Or simply use pip (or pip3):

```
pip install tensorflow-macos
```